# List products under each category heading in a single page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, categories

I have two tables
First one is **categories** and second one is **products**.
Categories table contains `cat_id, cat_name, Cat_desc.`
Products table contains `product_id, product_name, Product_desc and cat_id`

I want to display all categories as heading and list only 4 related products under each category heading.

For Eg:

```
Category1
 Product 1, Product 2, product 3


Category 2
  Product 4, product 5
```

How can I script this. I am newbie pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK i think this is ok with your question. try this...

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM  categories ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   echo $result['cat_name'];
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id=".$result['cat_id'];
   $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
   while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
      echo $row['product_name'];
   }
}
```

AND refer this http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Comment: How do I limit the number of products to be 4

Comment: Set for loop inside the product while loop. run for loop 4 time. So you can limit it or limit the result of product sql(LIMIT 0,4). Keep in touch with php.net.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Nytram's post, I just alter the code. So this answer is 99% owes to Nytram.

```
    $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM  categories ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
   echo $result['cat_name'];
```

And altered line is:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id='".$result['cat_id']."' LIMIT 0,10";
```

Then use the same code

```
 $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
       while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
          echo $row['product_name'];
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select * from 

categories c left join products p on (p.catId = c.catId)

order by c.catId
```

Comment: it will display only products in group. But not show each category heading. I need to display each and every category on the top of related products list.

Comment: YOu need to iterate through the resultset

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this tutorial
You need to do a **recursive function** for this
i call this ***category tree***

http://codeassembly.com/How-to-display-inifinit-depth-expandable-categories-using-php-and-javascript/